# Set position for foreignObject in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, binding, foreignobject

Can't set position (x, y) for foreignObject in Angular.

I've tried like this:

```
<foreignObject width="65" height="50" x="{{position?.x}}" y="{{position?.y}}">
   <div class="container">works!</div>
</foreignObject>
```

and

```
<foreignObject width="65" height="50" [x]="position?.x" [y]="position?.y">
   <div class="container">works!</div>
</foreignObject>
```

but with bindings gets error:

> Cannot set property x of [object SVGForeignObjectElement] which has only a getter

and it works if I set position like this:

```
<foreignObject width="65" height="50" x="100" y="100">
    <div class="container">works!</div>
</foreignObject>
```

How can I dynamically set position of `foreignObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision

Needs add local reference to foreignObject

```
<foreignObject width="65" height="50" #foreignFirst> <- here
   <div #container class="npz-container">works!</div>
</foreignObject>
```

Then in ts file needs add viewChild and attribute:

```
@ViewChild('foreignFirst') foreignFirst: ElementRef;

this.foreignFirst.nativeElement.setAttribute('x', this.position.x);
this.foreignFirst.nativeElement.setAttribute('y', this.position.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, your ForeignObject has x and y input properties, you can set;

```
<foreignObject width="65" height="50" [x]="position.x" [y]="position.y">
   <div class="container">works!</div>
</foreignObject>
```

You can create x object as Input property at `ForeignObject.Component.ts`:

```
private _position:any;  

@Input()
public get x(){ return position};
    
public set x(position:any){
    this._position=position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not work, gets the same error

Comment: I edited my answer can you control these?

Comment: yeah, it will work in angular component, but foreignObject is SVG tag [you can read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)